# How to make HTC Tattoo a Wi-Fi Hotspot

Tags: wifi-tethering, htc-tattoo

Can the HTC Tattoo act as a wifi hotspot, so that I am able to make my Tattoo an access point and share its internet connection with other wifi enabled devices? If so, how can I do this?

I have rooted the phone and I am running a CyanogenMod with Android version 2.2.1. I have already tried the following:

1. Barnacle wifi tether, Android wifi tether - neither of the two worked.
2. I have also seen if there were any default settings to make my phone a wi-fi hotspot, but found there were none of these settings in my phone.
3. I have also tried a new ROM: nFinity Android 2.3.5, but on this ROM also points 1) and 2) stated above were applicable.

Comment: It's possible the Tattoo's wifi chipset does not allow hostap mode. Try tethering with USB.

Answer (score 1):

There are some more suggested apps for the Tattoo [here on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1031208).  It sounds to me like they have stock firmware that is rooted, however — perhaps that's required.  I've heard of other devices that don't work for tethering with CyanogenMod (and I'm not familiar with nFinity).